# want to change color at multiple places in one go !

Tags: javascript, css

My problem is I have couple of divs in my page. All have header of similar color. Now if I have to change the color(for example background color) of all divs, I have to make changes as many divs I have. Is it not possible to just change or say write the color code at one place (like in a variable) and the then use that variable as color value in the embedded styles to all those divs. Something like javascript entities.

Comment: 1. Can you use jQuery? 2. Can you define "color" more exactly: Foreground (text) or background colour?

Comment: 1. I can use jQuery but I DO NOT WANT TO USE IT. 2. For now its background color, but if there is way I could do any change.

Comment: Why dont you want to use it, and why are you typing in caps?

Comment: Not wishing to use jQuery might actually be a Good Thing - by forcing yourself to go the hard way, you may learn the underlying JS (and CSS) that jQuery is wrapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need variables in CSS, you might want to look at CSS pre-compilers <sup>(is this the correct term?)</sup>, such as [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), which does this Server-side and eases the pains for having many different color repeated across multiple rulesets.

Otherwise, when developing, try splitting your CSS files into individual components, such as `typography.css`, `color.css` etc. to help better organise them. You'll still want to combine them after development is complete for better performance, but doing this does help keep things neater and tidier.

Lastly, you can always define large rules like this:

```
#header, #footer, #nav, #sidebar {
    color: orange; /* I like orange! */
}
```

Which would reduce redundancy somewhat. Using Javascript for styling and presentation should only be kept as a last resort; there are *always* tools available to keep your CSS tidy; you only need to use them.

Answer (score 2):

u can write some css and jquery to achive this

```
.color1
{
   color:red;
   background-color:green;
}

.color2
{
   color:blue;
   background-color:orange;
}
```

now on some event u can change classes. for example intitially u have

```
<div class="header color1">SOME TEXT HERE</div>
<div class="header color1">another header</div>
```

u can change this with jquery or even with javascript :)

```
$("#somebutton").live("click", function(){
    $(".header").removeClass('color1');
    $(".header").addClass('color2');

});
```

this will change color of both headers at click of button with id somebutton

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the same class on all divs and set all common colors in there? That way you'd only have to change the color for that class.

Comment: Don't really understand the down vote here? The questioner has specified they don't want to use jQuery and if the divs all share a common colour theme then using a class to define that is perfectly o.k. This also works in a browser that allows css but has javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or another javascript library, to do this.

Assign a class to the divs you wish to alter, and then use the following code (when giving them a clas of 'header-div')

```
$('.header-div').('background-color','#FF0000');
```

this will change ALL elements with the class of 'header-div'

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery solution**

define all the divs with a specific class like

```
<div class="changeable"></div>
```

Then use jquery to change the background

```
$(".change").click(function() {
    $(".changeable").css("background","#000");
});
```